# Marklogic - How to pass variable in inside the XML

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I need to insert the element in XML , so I have trying to create the some XML format using XQuery but its not working.

```
Query :

    let $a := 'test'
    return 
    <p name="uri" value= $a />

Expected output :

<p name="uri" value= "test" />
```

Kindly evaluate this .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let $a := 'test'
return 
<p name="uri" value="{$a}" />
```

Or:

```
let $a := 'test'
return 
<p name="uri">{ attribute value { $a } }</p>
```

The second expression provides a way to construct the name dynamically too as `{ $value }`.  Any attribute nodes constructed or placed inside an element body will be added as regular attributes of the element.